# Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type */* from javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget

Tags: java, jax-rs

I'm calling a JSON REST service using a `javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget` and specifying the media type as JSON. The service returns the correct content type as well. However, the `WebTarget` throws an exception stating:

> RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type */* and type class...

My code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:80/restservice");
Response response = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
response.readEntity(SomeClass.class);
```

Full exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type */* and 
type class SomeClass
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ClientReaderInterceptorContext.java:37)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:80)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:36)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:59)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:211)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:88)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.AbstractBuiltResponse.readEntity(AbstractBuiltResponse.java:262)
```

Comment: How do you know the server is sending the correct content-type? Did you actually inspect all the incoming headers? From what I see, the content-type header is set to `*/*` as that is what's in the error message. You can get the headers from the `Response`. Look at them. You can also set the content-type header to application/json before you readEntity(). This will work also. But if you control the server, try to figure out why it is sending this wrong header

Comment: You're right. The server was returning a 401 when called from the app. I had the authentication in my app wrong, but from Postman it was working. The 401 lacked the headers, the 200 has them. Stupid mistake. Thank you.